# Models with hasMany relationships have no values or attributes after update to 1.13

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've updated ember-data from 1.0.-beta.19.2  to 1.13.16 and my model "sheet" has a hasMany relationship ({ async: true, embedded: 'always' }) to another model "elements", which itself has a hasMany relationship to another model "steps" ({ async: true}). If I want to access steps in an observer in the elements model, it has no attributes or values. I've tried to make steps non async, because I don't know if that makes sense in an embedded record, but that didn't help.

My serializers for these models look like this

sheet:

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    isNewSerializerAPI: true,
    attrs: {
        elements: { embedded: 'always' },
        parent: { serialize: 'ids',  deserialize: 'records' }
    }
});
```

element:

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    isNewSerializerAPI: true,
    attrs: {
        steps: { embedded: 'always' }
    }
});
```

Comment: is `sheet.elements` a _promise_?, check `sheet.elements.toString()`.

Comment: Yes, that shows me <DS.PromiseManyArray:ember687>

Comment: The json from backend has steps though. But they seem to be missing in the observer "steps.content.@each" of the element model. Where can I look how this relationship is resolved? In the serializer for elements?

Comment: Ok, the problem lies within the serializer. It uses DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin which isn't supported by the new serializer API. I either need to make an own mixin that is able to handle embedded records as attributes instead of relations or not use the new API until ember-data 2.0

Comment: if you have found a solution to your problem try to add an answer to your own question, it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it didn't work after the update (without changing anything in the code) was a bit tricky to find. The steps model had no serializer defined, and automatically generated serializers default to `isNewSerializerAPI: true`. So the solution was just creating the file serializers/steps.js:

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {

});
```